# How to change default strong blue color in HTML form controls in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, input, defaultstyleddocument

[image]

Is there any workaround except using 3 rd css libraries to change default sharp blue styling of input elements? After such update the look of complicated interfaces happened to be completely inconsistent...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that the way a checkbox or similar inputs look can be changes with CSS, because they are part of the browser's interface. So what could you do?

CSS libraries are a solution, as you have already suggested.

If it was only the brightness of the blue colour you didn't like, an alternative could be to lay another element over each checkbox with a reduced opacity (a `div` with an absolute position and a white fill could be a solution).

The disadvantage of this approach is that it would require adding additional elements to your HTML, and the appearances available would still be very limited.

I would recommend creating your own checkboxes with CSS – it isn't actually that difficult, and the checkbox input elements can remain as they are now in the background.

I think that [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp) on w3schools might be quite useful for you. Maybe a little more work, but with the extra advantage that your checkboxes etc. look exactly the way you want them to, not just in chrome but in every browser.

Sorry I couldn't provide a single, simple solution, but I hope it helped a bit!

Comment: Well, this is the only workaround so far i see, thanks though, maybe you're right — who knows how else it will change

Comment: Not only checkboxes .... but all input elements. Select elements have options highlight in blue. Date and time inputs are blue. This blue is ... grrrr !